# How to add a custom property tab to the eclipse Properties view?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, view, properties, tabs

Basically, I have an eclipse plug-in which, among other things, adds three tabs to the Properties View, by using the extension points provided by eclipse (org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyContributor, org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs and org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections).

I am creating a plug-in to add a new tab (and some different properties) (see image).
[image]

Can you please give me some indications on how to do this, considering that there are no extension points offered by this plug-in for this. Is it possible to create a new tab by using the extension points provided by eclipse (mentioned above) in such a way that my tab appears under the three already added?
(I am pretty new in the plug-in area... all the tutorials I found showed how to create some tabs from scratch, where there is nothing added in the Properties View already).

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to contribute the tab like as usual, but from the other plugin?

Comment: Yes, I added the tab as usual, from the second plug-in. But it is not displayed. If I modify the original plug-in by adding the necessary tab and section, the Property tab is displayed.

Comment: The problem is that the original plug-in is part of a product consisting of various plug-ins (among which the one with the 3 tabs) and I am not supposed to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found so far (I still need to explore it a bit more - I might be able to add some more details):

- I created a fragment - the trick with the fragment is to either set the "host plugin" the RCP plugin or, if you set the "host plugin" a different plugin than the RCP, but which is in the Dependencies list of the RCP, you have to export the product first; don't forget to include the fragment in the Dependencies list of the product.
- I extended the plugin org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs and set the same contributorId as in the original plugin (the one with the 3 tabs) and created my new tab ("My Tab" in the image)
- I created the sections I needed for this tab, again setting the same contributorId